# How do you make your App open at login?

Tags: cocoa, authentication

Just wondering how I can make my app open automatically at login, but make this be able to be toggled on and off using a check box in the preferences window.

Comment: Which system are you targeting? It's different depending if you want 10.5, 10.4 or pre-10.4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a decent description of what to do at [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?StartingMyAppOnStartup).

Basically, you'll want to use the API in LaunchServices/LSSharedFileList.h if you can target  Mac OS X 10.5 or later. Before 10.5 there was no clean API, so you have to manually manipulate the login items ([Sample code at the Developer Connectiong](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/LoginItemsAE/index.html)).

Here's the [sample code](http://github.com/carpeaqua/Shared-File-List-Example)<sup>(dead)</sup> for Leopard I mentioned in the comments.  Found via [this blog post](http://carpeaqua.com/2008/03/01/adding-an-application-to-login-items-in-mac-os-x-leopard/). The code you need to enable or disable startup at login is in Controller.m.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to explain it.

Comment: Thats really old, I'm using leopard. Does it still work?

Comment: What you should be using is the LaunchServices/LSSharedFileList.h API. See http://secondgear-public.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SGLaunchAtLogin/ for some sample code. The code you need is in Controller.m

Comment: You can no longer use the `LSSharedFileList.h` methods for sandboxed apps in the Mac App Store: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html

Comment: Yes, doesn't work with SandBoxed apps which are now compulsory on Mac Appstore... Is there a turn around ??? Thanks !!

Answer (score 40):

Here's some code that I use, it's based on the Growl source.

```
+ (BOOL) willStartAtLogin:(NSURL *)itemURL
{
    Boolean foundIt=false;
    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (loginItems) {
        UInt32 seed = 0U;
        NSArray *currentLoginItems = [NSMakeCollectable(LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seed)) autorelease];
        for (id itemObject in currentLoginItems) {
            LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)itemObject;

            UInt32 resolutionFlags = kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction | kLSSharedFileListDoNotMountVolumes;
            CFURLRef URL = NULL;
            OSStatus err = LSSharedFileListItemResolve(item, resolutionFlags, &URL, /*outRef*/ NULL);
            if (err == noErr) {
                foundIt = CFEqual(URL, itemURL);
                CFRelease(URL);

                if (foundIt)
                    break;
            }
        }
        CFRelease(loginItems);
    }
    return (BOOL)foundIt;
}

+ (void) setStartAtLogin:(NSURL *)itemURL enabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    OSStatus status;
    LSSharedFileListItemRef existingItem = NULL;

    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (loginItems) {
        UInt32 seed = 0U;
        NSArray *currentLoginItems = [NSMakeCollectable(LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seed)) autorelease];
        for (id itemObject in currentLoginItems) {
            LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (LSSharedFileListItemRef)itemObject;

            UInt32 resolutionFlags = kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction | kLSSharedFileListDoNotMountVolumes;
            CFURLRef URL = NULL;
            OSStatus err = LSSharedFileListItemResolve(item, resolutionFlags, &URL, /*outRef*/ NULL);
            if (err == noErr) {
                Boolean foundIt = CFEqual(URL, itemURL);
                CFRelease(URL);

                if (foundIt) {
                    existingItem = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (enabled && (existingItem == NULL)) {
            LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(loginItems, kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst,
                                          NULL, NULL, (CFURLRef)itemURL, NULL, NULL);

        } else if (!enabled && (existingItem != NULL))
            LSSharedFileListItemRemove(loginItems, existingItem);

        CFRelease(loginItems);
    }       
}
```

If you want an easy to implement checkbox, make a `@property BOOL startAtLogin;` in one of your classes and implement it as follows. Just bind the checkbox value to the property and it should all work seamlessly.

```
- (NSURL *)appURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
}

- (BOOL)startAtLogin
{
    return [LoginItem willStartAtLogin:[self appURL]];
}

- (void)setStartAtLogin:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startAtLogin"];
    [LoginItem setStartAtLogin:[self appURL] enabled:enabled];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startAtLogin"];
}
```

Comment: This example, like most similar in existence, does not deal with the case where the app got deleted and then re-installed in another place after having been added to the Login Items - because it will then add another entry without removing the dead one. To do this right, before adding a new one, one should first look at all entries and remove any whose names start with the app's name.

Comment: Good point @ThomasTempelmann. But why entries *starting with* the app's name, rather than an exact match?

Comment: Nick, looking for the exact name is not good, because even if you only unzip an app twice, you already get a "-2" appended, and users then may end up starting that one. Users may also be inclined to rename your app (we're not on Windows, after all). Usually, the name will be appended to. But if your app's name is unique enough, look for your anywhere in the login items last path component. Or even locate each one and check their bundle ids - that's even more foolproof. Just be aware that some links may be dead.

Comment: I agree checking every bundle ID will be the best option. Or at the very least (if speed of checking every ID turns out to be an issue), check the bundle ID after making the partial name match - to ensure we're not removing the entry for an unrelated app with a similar name.

Comment: Does it work with new os releases high sierra and Mojave

Comment: Confirm this stopped working in Mojave

Answer (score 12):

Call the method pasted below with a file URL pointing at your application to add it to the current user's login items.

To disable again, you'll need to get that same loginListRef, convert it to an array, and iterate through it until you find the item with the url you want to disable.  Finally, call LSSharedFileListItemRemove with the appropriate arguments.

Good luck :)

```
- (void)enableLoginItemWithURL:(NSURL *)itemURL
{
    LSSharedFileListRef loginListRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);

    if (loginListRef) {
        // Insert the item at the bottom of Login Items list.
        LSSharedFileListItemRef loginItemRef = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(loginListRef, 
                                             kLSSharedFileListItemLast, 
                                             NULL, 
                                             NULL,
                                             (CFURLRef)itemURL, 
                                             NULL, 
                                             NULL);     
        if (loginItemRef) {
            CFRelease(loginItemRef);
        }
        CFRelease(loginListRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I replace this with: // Insert the item at the bottom of Login Items list. ? And how would I get that same loginListRef, convert it to an array, and iterate through it until you find the item with the url you want to disable?

Comment: Or just make it toggle using a checkbox, how would i do that?

Comment: Hi Joshua, There's quite a lot of ground to cover there.  The code I posted should help you figure out how to add something to the login items.  Actually hooking that up to a checkbox should be trivial if you're already a bit comfortable working on a Cocoa project.  If you're not, I'd recommend starting here: http://tinyurl.com/3z4r9b

Comment: How do I remove from the login list?

Comment: unfortunately this code is deprecated on 10.11

Answer (score 3):

See also SO question: [Register as login item with cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608963/register-as-login-item-with-cocoa)