# How do I add get an application to load on start-up

Tags: cocoa, macos, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Register as Login Item with Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608963/register-as-login-item-with-cocoa)

My Cocoa program needs to add an application to the start-up menu on a Mac.

Please let me know of any Cocoa code samples for doing this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anisha

Comment: start-up menu? you must have mixed windows and mac :-)

Answer (score 2):

There’s no such thing as *start-up menu* on Mac OS X. If you’re referring to login items, then your question is a duplicate of [Register as Login Item with Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608963/register-as-login-item-with-cocoa/).