# Add to login items, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Register as Login Item with Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608963/register-as-login-item-with-cocoa)

I am trying add my app in the login items (so it runs on startup) on the Mac. I will hook up a checkbox in my preferences to enable or disable this feature. On Windows you could just place a shortcut in the startup folder or use the registry, but how do you do it on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

apple's ux expects the user to use the integrated functionality of the system, provided in system preferences (if you have a daemon/agent, that's different).

so, you should generally follow the user's expectation (it's the mac way) and provide them with a message to add it to their startup items, and why it's important.

Comment: That's what the checkbox is for in the preferences dialog. I need to assume the user doesn't know how to add it manually and an oversized instruction dialog won't help.