# Create a script to run my cocoa application with a service

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to create a package, that should include my application, my pluggin and a script. The idea, is to create a script that leaves my application running as a service, because I need to launch my application on the computer start up. I read about services but I am new and it is hard for me to understand how to do it. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a “service” in the Windows sense or a “service” in the Mac OS X sense (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/)? They're different things.

Comment: I need that my application has the same behavior as "Growl" application. I have researched and what I need is to create a "Login Item" programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cite Growl as an example. Growl is:

1. A non-document-based application.
2. That runs in the background.
3. And adds itself (with the user's permission) to Login Items.

The first part is easy; Xcode has templates for that.

To make it run in the background, but still capable of showing UI, set `LSUIElement` in your Info.plist. If your app will never show UI, you probably want `LSBackgroundOnly` instead. Both of these are documented in the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/).

For the last part, [that's been previously covered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/608963/30461). (Updates to that answer: I left Growl a few months ago, and I'm pretty sure they're using LSSharedFileList now.)