# SMLoginItemSetEnabled - Start at Login with App Sandboxed - Xcode 6.3 (Illustration)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How to make app with Start at Login function when app sandboxed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you CORY BOHON, who created the following tutorial:

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/

I'll summary steps I have done:

1. Add StartAtLogin project
2. Import StartAtLoginHelper into StartAtLogin project
3. In StartAtLogin Build Phase, add Copy Files is StartAtLoginHelper with below config:

   3.1. Destination: Wrapper

   3.2. Subpath: Contents/Library/LoginItems
4. In StartAtLoginHelper, choose info.plist, add row "Application is background only" = YES
5. In StartAtLoginHelper Build Settings, change Skip Install in Release = YES
6. In StartAtLoginHelper, implement helper code

   NSArray *pathComponents = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] pathComponents];
   pathComponents = [pathComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [pathComponents count] - 4)];
   NSString *path = [NSString pathWithComponents:pathComponents];
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:path];
   [NSApp terminate:nil];

NSArray *a = nil;

7. In StartAtLogin, implement function call helper app

   SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.giauhuynh.StartAtLoginHelper", sender.state == NSOnState);
8. Code sign in + enable App Sandbox
9. Archive + Copy app to Applications folder and run

and my project:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03236580059305049920

Below is step by step fully (with illustration)

I. Setting up Main app

I.1. Add main app with name: StartAtLogin
[image]

I.2. Add helper app

I.2.1 Add a Target
[image]

I.2.2 Choose Cocoa Application
[image]

I.2.3 Name: StartAtLoginHelper
[image]

I.2.4 Add completely
[image]

I.3. add helper app to main app:”Contents/Library/LoginItems”

I.3.1 Choose Main App’s Build Phases
[image]

I.3.2 Add a new build phase
[image]

I.3.3 Select New Copy Files Phase
[image]

I.3.4 Copy Files section is still blank
[image]

I.3.5 Edit Destination, Subpath & add Helper app
[image]

I.4. Write SMLoginItemSetEnabled

I.4.1 Select main app’s MainMenu.xib
[image]

I.4.2 Add checkbox with name “Start at Login”
[image]

I.4.3 Set action
[image]

I.4.4 Select main app’s Build Phases
[image]

I.4.5 Import ServiceManagement.framework
[image]

I.4.6 Implement SMLoginItemSetEnabled code
[image]

II. Setting up Helper app

II.1. Application is background = YES

II.1.1 Select helper app’s Info
[image]

II.1.2 Add row
[image]

II.1.3 Add “Application is background only”, then set value is “YES”
[image]

II.2. Skip Install in Release = YES

II.2.1 Select helper app’s Build Settings, input word “skip” in search 
field
[image]

II.2.2 Expand Skip Install section
[image]

II.2.3 Set “Release” row is “YES”
[image]

II.3. Remove window

II.3.1 Select helper app’s MainMenu.xib
[image]

II.3.2 Remove StartAtLoginHelper’s window in xib file
[image]

II.4. Write helper code

II.4.1 Select helper app’s ApplicationDelegate.m
[image]

II.4.2 Implement helper code
[image]

III. Build and Testing

III.1. Code sign in + App Sandbox both Main app and Helper app

III.1.1 Code Sign In main app

III.1.1.1 Before Code Sign In 
[image]

III.1.1.2 After Code Sign In
[image]

III.1.2 Enable App Sandbox main app

III.1.2.1 Before Enable App Sandbox
[image]

III.1.2.2 After Enable App Sandbox
[image]

III.1.3 Code Sign In main app

III.1.3.1 Before Code Sign In 
[image]

III.1.3.2 After Code Sign In
[image]

III.1.4 Enable App Sandbox main app

III.1.4.1 Before Enable App Sandbox
[image]

III.1.4.2 After Enable App Sandbox
[image]

III.2. Archive + Copy app to Applications folder.

III.2.1 Archive

III.2.1.1 Select Product/ Archive
[image]

III.2.1.2 Waiting Xcode archiving
[image]

III.2.1.3 Select Export Button
[image]

III.2.1.4 Select Export as a Mac Application
[image]

III.2.1.5 Choose Desktop to Save
[image]

III.2.1.6 StartAtLogin app on Desktop
[image]

III.2.2 Copy app to Applications folder

III.2.2.1 Copy StartAtLogin app
[image]

III.2.2.2 Copy StartAtLogin app to Applications folder
[image]

III.2.3 Open app

III.2.3.1 Open StartAtLogin app
[image]

III.2.3.2 StartAtLogin app’s UI when started
[image]

III.2.3.3 Check Start at Login checkbox
[image]

III.2.3.4 Log Out (or Shut Down, Restart are OK)
[image]

III.2.3.5 Uncheck Reopen windows when logging back in, then Log Out
[image]

Comment: The line `SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.giauhuynh.StartAtLoginHelper", sender.state == NSOnState);`

writes warning "Implicit declaration of function SMLoginItemSetEnabled is invalid in C99". In 10.11. What does it mean?

Comment: @mirap, that means you need to add `#import <ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement.h>` to the top of file.